# How to reduce this code down to one line?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri.

I have the following code which replaces apostrophes with a standard one.

```
def replace_apostrophe(nokogiri_xml_doc)
  nokogiri_xml_doc.xpath('//text()').each {|node| node.content = node.content.gsub(/\b'|’|‛|⸂|⸄|⸌|⸜\b/, "'")}
  nokogiri_xml_doc 
end
```

I would like to reduce the method down to one line but I can't figure out how to make that happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it have to be one line? Just because? Code needs to be readable and easily understandable in order to be maintainable. Forcing code into a single line usually breaks at least one of those requirements, which will make it harder for whoever has to fix it at 3AM when it breaks. That's usually a very irate coworker, so consider that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'd much rather leave it as two lines; compacting it into one line might be "clever", but it makes the code harder to read.

If you really wanted to make this a one-liner, however, you can use `Object#tap`:

```
def replace_apostrophe(nokogiri_xml_doc)
  nokogiri_xml_doc.tap { |doc| doc.xpath('//text()').each { |node| node.content = node.content.gsub(/\b'|’|‛|⸂|⸄|⸌|⸜\b/, "'") } }
end
```

---

See the comments for useful information.

Comment: I tried to use gsub! and the code you suggested. However, when I do that the content does not get updated. It only seems to record the changes when I use the code as before with node.content = node.content.gsub... any ideas why?

Comment: @chell I guess `content()` returns an copy of the node content. Therefore `gsub!` has no effect on the original content.

Comment: @chell Ah.. yeah, maybe that won't work in this instance. (It will do usually, though.) Looking at [Nokogiri's source](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method), it appears a new copy of the content is being returned (`NOKOGIRI_STR_NEW2(content)`) - so mutating the object with `gsub!` won't work.

Comment: Don't add "edited" or "updated" tags when you make a change. Instead, incorporate the information into the response as if you'd written it initially. We can tell what has changed and when if necessary. Readability is more important than trying to maintain a visual log of changes in the text.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to reduce the method down to one line but I can't figure out how to make that happen.

You can always replace linebreaks with semicolons or keywords and write any code, no matter how complex on one line:

```
def replace_apostrophe(nokogiri_xml_doc) nokogiri_xml_doc.xpath('//text()').each {|node| node.content = node.content.gsub(/\b'|’|‛|⸂|⸄|⸌|⸜\b/, "'")}; nokogiri_xml_doc end
```

But, is that really better?

Comment: You could also make this code shorter, by only using single-letter method/variable names ;)

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't make it more readable ;-) The "myth" is that somehow writing code in one line makes it more readable, hence all the question about "how to write this in one line". I wanted to highlight that the question is meaningless in Ruby, since *everything* can be written in one line. Linebreaks as expression separators can be replaced with `;`, linebreaks as separators for conditions in conditionals or loops can be replaced with the respective keywords (`then` for `if`, `unless`, and `case`, `do` for `while` and `for`), linebreaks for separating the name of a method from its …

Comment: … body can be replaced with an empty parameter list `()` or a `;`, and so on and so forth. Even linebreaks in multiline strings can be replaced with the `\n` escape.

Comment: I was only winding you up... But while we're at it, let's stop using methods entirely, and define everything with stabby lambda syntax. :D